# How can I generate a Minecraft world with no stone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I want to generate a world where all blocks (dirt, gravel, trees, granite, andesite, diorite, all ores, etc...) spawn normally but with no stone. I want a natural selection of other blocks replacing the stone as opposed to air replacing the blocks. If I want a vanilla world otherwise how can I do this? I have some coding experience in Java but none with editing Minecraft with mods.

Comment: As far as I know, this can actually be done without mods, but I'm not entirely familiar with how the custom gen works

Comment: Generating a custom world gives sliders for all the blocks I want to spawn normally (none maxed out for default values) but there is no slider for stone. Unfortunately maxing out the sliders for both spawn tries and spawn size for dirt, gravel, andesite, diorite and granite reduces but doesn't eliminate stone from the environment.

Comment: This sounds like a job for MCEdit...

Comment: In theory you can set up an limited world and an GIANT command block structure that will replace stone randomly with other blocks

Comment: @ModDL You wouldn't need a "GIANT command block structure", and replacing methodically would work better than randomly (check blocks in order and replaces stone with a block from a set of nat gen blocks using clone). This method would not produce proper veins of say... andesite, but at least it would work consistently and not be simply solid stone.

Comment: @byteoflogic this sounds like the best solution so far, my only question is would that remove non-natural sources of stone (like pouring lava over water) or just when the chunks were generated?

Comment: @user145462 Just when the command is ran, and if done is created while the command is running, there would be no guarantee they would be replaced.

Answer (score 7):

As you said "natural selection of other blocks", you will not get any blocks. There is a complex formula that tells the game what blocks may spawn at what location, which includes depth.

In other words: It's not possible to get a natural selection of other blocks to replace the stone.

The custom generator for Minecraft allows you to generate worlds without stone, but you will have to define the exact layout of the world, which is not generated as you want it to be.

Last resort: A custom mod. Downsides to this are that you most likely cannot update your game and world if the game gets an update, without losing most of the new features, or without losing the functionality of the mod. Also, if you want to play with friends, you will need to host a server, which requires a lot more RAM compared to just sharing your world through the game client.

Comment: Updating the game should work fine, but you'll need to update the mod and make sure to use the version that corresponds to the game version. The update feature of MCreator is actually good, although you'll probably cringe pretty hard at its workarounds and ESPECIALLY at the datapack content it makes.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use http://minecraft.tools/en/custom.php to generate a custom world with custom blocks, and then import it into your save or server folder.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do the following:

1. Go to `Create New World`.
2. Name your world.
3. Go to `More World Options`.
4. Change the `World Type` to Superflat. Note: Sadly it's a flat world but in
   the newer versions the world customizations are better applied for
   the user.
5. Go to `Customize`.
6. After that click on those materials that spawn and you can remove
   them.

Comment: I think he ASKED for a not flat world